# Understand clustered tables in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

How data is structured in BigQuery when tables are partitioned and what are differences between Oracle Cluster and BigQuery Clustered tables?

> When you create a clustered table in BigQuery, the table data is
>   automatically organized based on the contents of one or more columns
>   in the table’s schema. [link](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/clustered-tables)

Do they mean that some indexing is done or?

Comment: It means sorting, not indexing. Check out https://youtu.be/1gYUGv_omJA about 12 minutes in for a visual explanation.

Comment: Can you please add this as an answer?

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned by [Elliott](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6253347/elliott-brossard) in the comment above:

> It means sorting, not indexing. Check out [youtu.be/1gYUGv_omJA](https://youtu.be/1gYUGv_omJA) about
>   12 minutes in for a visual explanation.